# Is there a Stack Exchange site for topics related to sales/accounting/inventory valuation?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Are any of the SE sites a suitable place to ask questions about perpetual inventory valuation, which is about keeping track of the value of the inventory/stock of materials you own?

A bit related to accounting.

Comment: Welcome to [meta.se]. Have you already reviewed the list of sites on https://stackexchange.com/sites?

Comment: Out of all sites that I remember, only [money.se] came out, but I don't know if your question will be [on-topic or not on there](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).